# WSO2 ESB unable to use multiple custom mediators in same package

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm trying to create a multiple mediators inside same java packages. e.g.

com.samples.wso2

However when 2 or more mediators are deployed using same package name, ESB will find just one mediator class. If unique package name is used for different mediators then all are found. Didn't find any information about this but seems like a bug to me. Can somebody confirm this ? Thanks,

Version used 4.8.0.

Comment: Do you have the java classes (with the com.samples.wso2 namespace) in different .jars ? The same namespace cannot be used in two different .jar files. As `com.samples.com` may already taken - choose a different namespace.

Comment: Yes actually those are in different jars so in that case it makes sense why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 custom mediators ("genuine" mediators, with xml conf, not class mediators) in the same package in WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 without problem

You should verify your META-INF/services/org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactory and MediatorSerializer files : you need two lines in each file, to reference factories and serializers for each mediator

Comment: ok, good to know about "custom genuine" mediators. For simplicity I prefer more custom Class mediators since there's already support in WSO2 Eclipse plugin which makes the deployment easy.